# How to specify returning view from a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

That's the controller I have:

```csharp
public ActionResult LabPreparation(int? id)
{
    if (id == null) return new HttpNotFoundResult();

    var lab = db.Labs.Find(id);
    if (lab == null) return HttpNotFound();

    return View(lab);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("LabPreparation", "Lab", new {id = item.Id})'">Preparation</button>
```

Lab is a model and I have different view for each lab. How can I specify views, that controller should return for a special lab?

Comment: **return View("ViewName", lab)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the view that should be used, like:

```
 return View("viewname", lab);
```

If the view is in a different folder, you can use the full path:

```
 return View("~/Views/Folder/ViewName.aspx").
```

EDIT:

In order to decide about what view to show, you could create a Dictionary that links ID's to view names:

```
 var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 dictionary.Add("1", "ViewName.aspx");
 etc...
```

and use that like:

```
 return View(dictionary[id], lab);
```

(and add some exception handling, of course, for example in case ID does not exist)

Comment: Might be useful to include how one could return a View that is located in a different subfolder....

Comment: The problem is, that I have about 30 views. That way I should use that code 30-times?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can create a dictionary where you link keys to view names, and use that. You have to define the links somehow, but it is not clear in your question how that should work. How do you decide what view to use?

Comment: One way or another you're going to have to identify the name of the view, and then `return View(viewName, lab);` will work as per this answer.

Comment: @L-Three , there is a table with several rows, when you click on a cell, controller gets an Id of the cell and returning a view (new page in browser) with content for that id.

Comment: So you have to map id's to views? See updated answer.

Comment: @L-Three, yes, that's what i need. Is there any way to automatically add links to dictionary?

Comment: That's where SO is for ;)